# How get values passed by GET after of the symbol "#"?

Tags: php, api, oauth

I like used OAuth 2.0 from GOOGLE.

When I open:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=openid+profile+email&response_type=token&redirect_uri=MYWEB&client_id=MYID.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

I get exactly:

```
MYWEB/#access_token=BEAUTIFULL.TOKEN&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&authuser=0&hd=MYEMAIL&session_state=BEAUTIFULL.SESSION&prompt=none
```

I unknow for what google give to me this four parameters, (GOOGLE give to a TOKEN valid!):

```
authuser = 0
hd = MYEMAIL
session_state = BEAUTIFULL.SESSION
prompt = none
```

however, the more important (and the real motive of my post) is:

PHP no take this vars becouse the symbol "#" is present in the answer from GOOGLE, then my server/PHP no take any of this values.

How I can get ALL the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] (var => value) after of symbol "#" ???

Logically GOOGLE know this "#" avoid take the response, then why/for what, this symbol is present in the answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `explode()` function breaks a sting apart by a specified character and stores each part in an array.  You can use it to separate your string, first by `&` to get each key/val pair. Then by `=` to separate the key from the value.

So, this should work for you:

```
$input = 'MYWEB/#access_token=BEAUTIFULL.TOKEN&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&authuser=0&hd=MYEMAIL&session_state=BEAUTIFULL.SESSION&prompt=none';
print_r(getGetVars($input));

function getGetVars($string){
    $output = Array();

    // find #
    if(!$hashPos = strpos($string, '#')) return 'error: # not found';

    // trim string to only include text after #
    $string = substr($string, $hashPos + 1);

    // break string apart by &
    $keysAndVals = explode('&', $string);

    foreach($keysAndVals as $keyValString){
        // seperate key and value on each side of =
        $keyValArray = explode('=', $keyValString);

        $key = $keyValArray[0];
        $val = $keyValArray[1];

        $output[$key] = $val;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Not's possible do "$input=xxx", the values exist in $_GET, no INTO script!, just the problem no is "how do a explode", my problem is get the values from $_GET.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I misunderstood what you were saying.  What do you mean "when I go to xxx"  then I "get exactly zzz" ?

Comment: Thanks BB, the info exist in: $_GET, no into SCRIPT.

Comment: It is in the $_GET or in the URI... or both?

Comment: $_GET is only populated when a get request is made to your page.  It looks like you are making a request to a different page and getting a response back.

Comment: Please post your code so I can understand what you are doing..!

Comment: This answer comming from GOOGLE.

But try yourself:

 <a href="http://YOURWEB/#var1=1&var2=2">BB</a>

Problem no is "from where arrive values", problem no is:

 $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

the problem is catch $_GET when this start with symbol "#".